# Maximum sum of non-contiguous array elements that is divisible by K

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array `ar` with `n` elements, find the maximum sum in array that is divisible by `K`. The elements used in the sum need not be contiguous.

Example: For `N = 4` and `ar = [2,2,1,2]` and `K = 3`, answer would be 6 (including elements 2, 2 and 2).

Comment: Is the number of sum elements limited by K?

Comment: Interesting question.  A good first step would, I guess, be to take the mod of each individual element, cut them each down to fit inside the finite field.  But that is just prep work and in your example is not even needed.  Wow, I can only think to do trial and error (2^n)-1 operations where n is the number of elements in the array, but stopping when we find a combo X such that the mod of X+1 = 0.  But there has to be a better way.

Comment: @Henry - Sorry maybe I left the question ambiguous. The last part is that the max sum should be divisible by K

Comment: So this isn't about modular arithmetic at all, which is how I read the title. I've taken the liberty to update the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem.

Let `dp[i] = true if we can build sum i and false otherwise`.

```
dp[0] = true
s = 0
for each number x in the array:
  s += x
  for j = s down to x
    dp[j] = dp[j] OR dp[j - x]
```

Then find the largest `j <= s` such that `j % k == 0` and `dp[j] == true`.